# After symbolic link: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, vagrant, symlink

For a vagrant box i created a bootstrap script that makes my mysql data persistent. It's run through a provisioner shell script with privileged rights.

Basically the script creates a symbolic from /var/lib/mysql -> /vagrant/mysqldata
The /vagrant folder is mounted to the host system so after creating this symbolic link all data in mysql reappears

```
    if [ ! -L /var/lib/mysql ] ; then
        sudo service mysql stop
        sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old
        sudo ln -s /vagrant/mysqldata /var/lib/mysql
        sudo echo "alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> /vagrant/mysqldata/," >> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias
        sudo service apparmor reload
        sudo service mysql start
    fi
```

Problem is, after I've ran this script and afterwards I run `vagrant reload --provision` it always fails with the error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

However, if i ssh into vagrant and manually start mysql, it works. I'm not sure what's the issue here.

As you see in the script it renames the old mysql data folder to mysql-old, it I set that back it works again. So it has something to do with that symlink.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the /vagrant mount for your data dir. That interface is flaky and has poor performance. What I've done instead is use the [vagrant plugin for persistent storage](https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage) and put the MySQL data on this volume. That way I could make MySQL data survive vagrant destroy and recreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bill Karwin commented, I used the [persistent storage plugin](https://github.com/kusnier/vagrant-persistent-storage) for vagrant which does exactly what I want.